# How to stop vsftpd server

Tags: bash, scripting, vsftpd

I downloaded the vsftpd file (The latest vsftpd release is [v3.0.3](https://security.appspot.com/downloads/vsftpd-3.0.3.tar.gz)) and manually installed it.

I then started the server using the command `./vsftpd_v1 vsftpd_v1.conf`
and terminated it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>. When I tried to start it again using the same command it showed the following error:

> 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

I searched the error and found that it means that server is already is running so could not bind another. So I am trying to stop the server but are not able to do. Like if I directly install it then I can use `service ./vsftpd_v1 stop`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). That said, you can simply type `ps -axf | grep vsftp` to get the current running instance (add `| grep -v grep` if you don't want to see the `grep` command included in the output. Then `kill pid_of_vsftp`. (or `sudo killall vsftpd`)

Comment: If you don't find anything with `ps  -axf | grep vsftp`, then have you attempted to start another ftp server? Try `ps -axf | grep ftp` and generally search of `ftp`. Also, as in the answer, you can type `fg` to bring any backgrounded process back to the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, you did not stop but rather suspend the server. You can list the stopped programs using `jobs` and can switch back to one with `fg`. You can find more information on jobs in the [Bash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (`man bash`, see "Job Control").

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> instead to abort your program.